# Is "variation" the correct word to use here?

Tags: word-choice

There is an idiomatic phrase in my native language whose meaning changes if another phrase is added to it. I am wondering if "variation" is the correct word to describe the new phrase.

A similar example from English:

1. For the better.
2. For better or for worse.

Can we say that phrase 2 is a variation of phrase 1?

Comment: Yes, expressions can have variations. But the ones you gave mean different things.

Comment: Idiomatically, [Brits in particular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+a+variation+of%2Cis+a+variant+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) are more likely to say that phrase 2 is a ***variant*** of phrase 1

Comment: Yup, those are completely different sayings, unrelated in meaning. They are not variations of the same thing.

Comment: Almost any phrase can change it's meaning if you add more phrases to it.